# EXT JS 5 - Custome Filter for hours and minutes

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, extjs5

I have value in minutes and i converted into hours and minutes (e.g like 615 minutes=10 hours and 15 minutes) and displayed in grid. by default ext js 5 is providing filter by string. But i want to filter by hours and minutes. Is it possible? if so, let me know.

Comment: Is it a local or remote filter? Can you provide code or screenshot as well?

Comment: Assuming that you are talking about the gridfilters plugin, then yes, you could do this pretty easily by creating your own custom filter.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily extend `Ext.grid.filters.filter.String` filter to do that.

Example code which uses timefield:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.grid.filters.filter.Time', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.filters.filter.String',
    alias: 'grid.filter.time',

    type: 'time',
    operator: 'eq',

    // change item template to timefield
    itemDefaults: {
        xtype: 'timefield',
        enableKeyEvents: true,
        format: 'H:i',
        hideEmptyLabel: false,
        iconCls: Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-filters-find',
        labelSeparator: '',
        labelWidth: 29,
        margin: 0,
        selectOnFocus: true
    },
    createMenu: function () {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent();

        // add handler to change event
        me.inputItem.on({
            scope: me,
            change: {
                fn: me.onChange,
                buffer: 200
            }
        });
    },
    // handle change event
    onChange: function(field) {
        this.setValue(field.getValue());
    },
    // set value - value comes as date
    setValue: function (value) {
        var me = this;

        if (me.inputItem) {
            me.inputItem.setValue(value);
        }

        // convert date to number
        me.filter.setValue(value.getHours() * 60 + value.getMinutes());

        if (value && me.active) {
            me.updateStoreFilter(me.filter);
        } else {
            me.setActive(!!value);
        }
    },
    activateMenu: function () {
        var value = this.filter.getValue();

        // convert number back to date
        this.inputItem.setValue(
            new Date(2008, 0, 1, Math.floor(value / 60), (value % 60), 0)
        );
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dw82uxkh/9/

Comment: Thanks for solution but little change is required. When we filter time column it is filtering string in 01:32 format but we have 1:32. So, it will not filter 1:32.